# PHP image upload - rename without losing extension?

Tags: php, file

I currently have:

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['name'];
$random_digit=rand(0000,9999);
$new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;
$path= "uploads/images/users/".$new_file_name;
if($ufile !=none)
{
    if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path))
    {
        echo "Successful<BR/>"; 
        echo "File Name :".$new_file_name."<BR/>"; 
        echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['size']."<BR/>"; 
        echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['type']."<BR/>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

this generates a random number before the current file name ie 4593example.jpg
but i would just like it to rewrite the whole filename to 4593.jpg removing the ucrrent name (example). When i have tried doing this i lose the extension (.jpg)
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$newFilename = $random_digit . '.' . $ext;
```

BTW, what will happen if the random number clashes (which may happen next or in 10 years)?

There are many better ways to name them - for example, hash of the filename and `time()` should theoretically never clash (though in practice hash collisions do occur).

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with images only, I would consider detecting the image's type using [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and giving the new file an extension according to that.

That way, you don't have to rely on what extension you get from the user (which could be wrong).

Like so:

```
$extensions = array(
  IMAGETYPE_JPG => "jpg",
  IMAGETYPE_GIF => "gif",
  IMAGETYPE_PNG => "png",
  IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000 => "jpg",
  /* ...... several more at http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php 
            I'm too lazy to type them up */

 );

$info = getimagesize($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name']); 
$type = $info[2];

$extension = $extensions[$type];

if (!$extension) die ("Unknown file type");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path.".".$extension);
```

`
Also:

- As @alex says, your method has a considerable risk of collisions of random names. You should add a `file_exists()` check to prevent those (e.g. a loop that creates a new random number until one is found that doesn't exist yet)
- `HTTP_POST_FILES` is deprecated, use `$_FILES` instead
- I strongly advise you to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) instead of `copy()` which is vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Which attacks can occur using `copy()`? Thanks.

Comment: @alex there is/was a vulnerability - `move_uploaded_file()` was introduced in response to it. I actually broke into a friend's phpBB once with this in 2000 or something :) Hang on, I'll check whether I can find a link.

Comment: @alex weird, I can't find a link right now. Anyway, the gist of it was that you were able to overwrite `$_FILES["xyz"]["tmp_name"]` and put a local file path in it. If you knew the attacked app's structure, you could e.g. get the database configuration file this way. `copy()` would stupidly copy the config file to the new location, from which you were able to download it if the upload was e.g. for an avatar image. `move_uploaded_file()` will move only actually uploaded files

Answer (score 3):

You can get the original extension by using the following code:

`$extension = strrchr($HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], '.');`

Then you can add the extension to the variable `$new_file_name` like this:

`$new_file_name = $random_digit . $file_name . '.' . $extension;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['name']; $random_digit=rand(0000,9999); 
$extension= end(explode(".", $HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['name']));
$new_file_name=$random_digit.'.'.$extension; $path= "uploads/images/users/".$new_file_name; if($ufile !=none) { if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path)) { echo "Successful
"; echo "File Name :".$new_file_name."
"; echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['size']."
"; echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['type']."
"; } else { echo "Error"; } }
```

enjoy!!!!!!!!!