# PHP Upload - Allow only jpg files

Tags: php, file, upload, restriction

This is what I currently have:

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['name'];
$user= 'FILENAME';
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_file_name=$user . '.' . $ext;
$path= "uploads/images/users/".$new_file_name;
if($ufile !=none)
{
  if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['tmp_name'], $path))
  {
  echo "Successful<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Name :".$new_file_name."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['size']."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['type']."<BR/>"; 
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Error";
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the getimagesize() method showed in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141032/php-image-upload-rename-without-losing-extension)

Comment: This isn't the best way to ask a question. What is your problem? What do you need help with, does the above code do what you would expect?

Comment: Just FYI, `HTTP_POST_FILES` has been deprecated for *years*; use `$_FILES` instead unless you're forced to develop for PHP4 (does anyone still do that?)

Comment: As well, don't use `copy()` to handle uploaded files. PHP has `move_uploaded_file()` specifically for this purpose, which has some extra checks to foil server-side attacks on the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$allowedTypes = array('image/jpeg');

$fileType = $HTTP_POST_FILES['uid']['type'];

if(!in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes)) {
    // do whatever you need to say that
    // it is an invalid type eg:
    die('You may only upload jpeg images');
}

?>
```

hope this helps. Also why are you using HTTP_POST_FILES instead of $_FILES? Are you working with an older version of PHP?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this method relies on content type data sent by the browser and can be manipulated. Using `getimagesize()` would be better

Comment: I have now changed from using copy and HTTP_POST_FILES but still unsure on how to allow only jpg's - everything iv tried gives the error but still uploads or uploads nothing including the jpg files

Comment: is this safe against uploading php scripts to RCE?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever ever trust that happening. It's unsafe and could potentially lead to people screwing up with your server. Try this instead http://ar.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg

```
<?php
function LoadJpeg($imgname){
    /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);

    if(!$im){ 
       throw new InvalidArgumentException("$imgname is not a JPEG image");
    }  

    return $im;
}
?>
```

Using it like so:

```
$uploadDir = "/path/to/uploads/directory";
$handle = LoadJpeg($_FILES['uid']['tmp_name']);
imagejpeg($handle, $uploadDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['uid']['name']);
```

Comment: I have now changed from using copy and HTTP_POST_FILES but still unsure on how to allow only jpg's - everything iv tried gives the error but still uploads or uploads nothing including the jpg files..

Comment: Doing this will effectively avoid using any files that are not JPEGs, but if what you want is the actual upload to end half way through then probably need to do your uploading with flash