# PHP upload image file types problems

Tags: php

I am new with the upload function in php howover i have this :

```
if( $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/gif"

                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/jpeg"
                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/jpg"
                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/pjpeg"
                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/x-png"
                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] !== "image/png"
                || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'] == "application/x-rar-compressed"
           ){

                 $error = 'wrong file only :GIF,jpg,png .';
 //    die($_FILES[$fileElementName]['type']);  // also i did die here to check
    }
```

But it wont working it will say always wrong even if i upload jpg.
I did die/var_damp and its all okay the type is working for E.G:
I upload sds.jpg and i make die its giving correct:

```
image/jpeg
```

But it will keep says always wrong file why?

Comment: Swap your `||` for `&&`. What's happening is that your statement is true if (it's not a gif) or (it's not a jpg) - and since you're uploading a jpg, the gif one will always be true.

Comment: A much cleaner way would be `if (!in_array($_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'], array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png',.....))) {// bad type...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look here the source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5143683)

**Try more shorter and better variant like this:**

```
 $allowedTypes = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg' ,'image/pjpeg' ,'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'application/x-rar-compressed');

$fileType = $_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'];

if(!in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes)) {
    // do whatever you need to say that
    // it is an invalid type eg:
    die('You may only upload jpeg images');
}
```

Comment: The code in this answer is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5143683

Comment: As you can see,I fund an answer and make a little bit correct to this qusetion, what is the problem? I do not understand...

Comment: You did not link to the source. Without linking to it, it makes it look like you wrote this answer yourself, which you did not.

Comment: Hm, but I thought he also was searching, maybr he saw this but can not implement to his question. That's why I sugest to make the right variant to him

Comment: I understood. ok. I will do it in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the conditional `&&` (and) rather than `||` (OR)

To avoid a massive statement, which would be hard to maintain, I would use an array.

```
$allowedtypes = array(
  'image/jpg',
  'image/jpeg',
  //..etc
);

if (! in_array($_FILES[$fileElementName]['type'], $allowedTypes)) {
 // not allowed
} else {
 // allowed
}
```

Comment: You sure it first is Allowed ? i think you confused its Noy allowed and the other is allowed , i using the other answer its the same.. btw thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ravg woops, you're right, the comments are the wrong way around